# Array of queue container in c++

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I am beginner in c++, But I have to implement some advance stuff in my project.
Basically I want to create the array of queue container. I have one device class, which is having queue of type op_parmas_t and application enqueues in that queue. But now i want different thread operate on different queues but single device , So i need array of queue in device class.

```
class DeviceCPU : publice Device {
Public:
      DeviceCPU();
      ~DeviceCPU();
      int enqueue(op_params_t *op);
Private:
      std::queue<op_params_t *> opsEnqueued;
}
```

but for multiple threads, I want different queues. So i want to create array of queue,
Something like,

```
std::queue<op_params_t *> opsEnqueued[MAX_THREADS];
```

or may be i can create the vector of queue, but i don't know exactly how, Need some pointers.

Comment: All of the necessary pointers are already here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Comment: The code you present - `std::queue<op_params_t *> opsEnqueued[MAX_THREADS]; ` - is indeed an array of `queue`s... did you try it, and if so what specific problem did you have with it?  As you say, a `std::vector<std::queue<>>` is another option - whether that's more convenient or resource friendly depends on how you code uses it... hopefully you'll realise which is better as you program your app.

Comment: I would also like to understand why people are downvoting the question. May be i can then make it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::queue<op_params_t*>, MAX_THREADS> opsEnqueued;
```

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic array

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::queue<op_params_t *>> opsEnqueued;
```